# Characteristic function of $p(x) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}$, $-\infty < x < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let X denote a real-valued random variable with an absolutely continuous distribution with density function  $p(x) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|}$, $-\infty < x < \infty$.

Find the characteristic function.

Attempt:

I know that the setup should look something like this:

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx} e^{-|x|} \;dx $$

Comment: Where are you getting $x^2$ from?? The characteristic function is by definition $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx}\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}dx$. Also, $\exp(ab)\neq \exp(a)\exp(b)$.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. I had some difficulty writing out the code in LaTeX. Not sure how to proceed from the initial point.

Comment: Just compute the integral.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Clearly we have to resolve the absolute value sign to evaluate the integral using standard techniques. It will be helpful to divide the integral into two parts according to the domains where $e^{-|x|}$ becomes well-behaving function which is easy to integrate.

Comment: So far I have:

$\frac{1}{2}$ $e^{it}$ $\int_{-\infty}^0$$e^{2x}$dx + $\frac{1}{2}$ $e^{it}$$\int_0^{\infty}$1dx.


Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

The characteristic function is

$$\begin{align} \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} e^{i t x} ~dx &= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{x+i t x} ~dx + \frac12 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x + i t x} ~dx\\ &= \frac12 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(1+i t) x}  ~dx + \frac12 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(1-i t) x} ~dx\\ &= \frac12 \frac{1}{1+i t} + \frac12 \frac{1}{1-i t}\\ &= \frac{1}{1+t^2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Much simpler than mine if you aren't afraid of complex numbers :D.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $(a+bi)+(a-bi)=2a$ so by splitting the integral at $0$
$$
\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx}e^{-|x|}dx = \int_0^\infty \mathfrak{Re}(e^{itx}e^{-x})dx
$$
$$
=\int_0^\infty \cos(tx)e^{-x}dx
$$
$$
=e^{-x}\frac{t\sin(tx)-\cos(tx)}{t^2+1}\biggr|_{x=0}^{\infty}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{1+t^2}.
$$
I will leave the calculation of the integral (by parts twice) to you.